# HTML linking image to image to image

Tags: html

Html- i am writing a program so that the user clicks on an image and is linked to another image and to another i can do it for one image but am struggling with the code to make the second image link to the third and so on any suggestions greatly appreciated?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Untitled</title>
</head>
<body>

    <script language="JavaScript">
        var clockID = 0;
        function UpdateClock() {
            if(clockID) {
                clearTimeout(clockID);
                clockID  = 0;
            }
            var tDate = new Date();
            document.theClock.theTime.value = "" 
                + tDate.getHours() `enter code here`+ ":" 
                + tDate.getMinutes() + ":" 
                + tDate.getSeconds();
            clockID = setTimeout("UpdateClock()", 1000);
        }
        function StartClock() {
            clockID = setTimeout("UpdateClock()", 500);
        }
        function KillClock() {
            if(clockID) {
                clearTimeout(clockID);
                clockID  = 0;
            }
        }
    </script>


    <body onload="StartClock()" onunload="KillClock()">
        <form name="theClock">
            <input type=text name="theTime" size=8 style="text-align: center">
        </form>

    <font face="Tahoma"><a target="_blank" href="http://www.htmlfreecodes.com/"><span style="font-size: 8pt; text-decoration: none"></span></a></font>

    <A HREF = "img2.png">
        <img src= "img1.png">
        <!--<A HREF = "img4.png">
                <img src= "img3.png"> </a>-->
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can you post your code so far?

Comment: I've built something similar @ http://daroom.info/index.php?rand=785

Comment: Welcome to SO. What have you tried? Are you writing pure HTML or using a programing language to generate the pages? Are you using JavaScript?

Comment: Hi I basically  have to link six images by clicking on them, i have  some javascript displaying the time, I'm pretty new to programming,i'm wondering can i just use html for linking the pages or do i need some javascript,thanks for replying

Comment: Why the downvotes? The asker is clearly new to html + javascript